# Why I need to a refresh token for refreh access token

Tags: oauth, access-token

I'm  implementing oauth automatic login via Asp.net Web API and OWIN . My question is ; Why I need for a refresh token to refresh access token .I think I can detect if access token has expired , then I can refresh it without any credential check and then I can return new access token to the client . So why need for a refresh token ?  An other subject is why refresh token is more secure then access token ?  Both  comes in same server reponse.

Comment: It sounds like you are asking two different questions - what is a refresh token used for, and security around refresh tokens. Please separate them into two questions.

Comment: Can you provide more details? Are you implementing an OAuth 2.0 client? Who is hosting the resource / authorization server(s)? Are you talking about a client credential check, or a user credential check?

Comment: Actually I want to learn what is purpose of refresh token or why I need It ? I think  when an access token expired ,I can refresh access token  without a refresh token .  For examle lets say we have an expired access token and when I notice that situation I can generate new one . I don't need to refresfh token  or any thing  .

Answer (score 1):

A refresh token does not require going through any of the grant flows again, which requires (most of them anyway) interaction with the resource owner. The client is allowed to obtain access tokens whenever they want without the resource owner being involved.

For further reading and examples, check out Google's [offline access](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2WebServer#offline).